# Generic template template parameter that matches a class whose template parameters include integrals

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

A template template parameter like

```
typename< template<typename...> C, /* other types */ >
...
```

will fail to patch when the first parameter is templated on integral values, in addition to types (for example, the popular tsl::robin_map hash map type, which has a bool among its template arguments). Some of the special cases can probably be caught with constructs like

```
template< template<bool, typename...>  C, /* etc */>
...
template< template<typename, bool, typename...>  C, /* etc */>
...
template< template<typename, typename, bool, typename...>  C, /* etc */>
...
```

where the requirement that a parameter pack must be the final parameter cause a bit of pain.

Is there any generic way to match such types?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can't mix type and non-type template parameters like that. You'll have to find some workaround. What exactly are you trying to do? Depending on that, there might be different solutions that work.

Comment: What about insert `std::true_type` or `std::false_type` instead a bool value? This way the `bool` become a type so you can catch all cases with `typename...`

Comment: @max66 I don't have control over that; note the example case from the popular robin_map library.

Comment: @cigien My workaround for now, since the only cases that matter to me now are tsl::robin_set and tsl::robin_map, which each have a single boolean parameter, is to special-case them by creating two templated aliases for each of them with the boolean parameter true/false respectively, so that all remaining template parameters are types and my library methods work on them. Maybe that's the best I'll be able to o.